# Select the Latest Message Between the communication of two user in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table maintaining messages between users. The table structure looks like

```
     sender    receiver   message   sendtime
      1          2          m1      2012-01-01 12:12:12  
      2          1          m2      2012-01-01 12:50:20
      1          2          m3      2012-01-01 12:55:55
      1          3          m4      2012-01-02 05:05:05
      1          4          m5      2012-01-05 05:20:20
      4          1          m6      2012-01-06 06:05:00
      4          1          m7      2012-01-07 11:11:11
      2          4          m8      2012-01-08 05:01:01
```

Now, for the user with ID 1, I need the result like this

```
    sender     receiver   message   sendtime
     1           2          m3      2012-01-01 12:55:55
     1           3          m4      2012-01-02 05:05:05
     4           1          m7      2012-01-07 11:11:11
```

That is I need the recent messages for the particular user whether he is sender or receiver.

Though, it seem easy, I cannot find a way to write a single mysql query.

Also, I want suggestion if for this kind of solution, my table design is poor.

Note: One thing, which I think I should mention is, for instance there are multiple communication between user 1 and user 2. I need the latest communication between them two whether user 1 is a sender or receiver, only the recent.

Most users are suggesting the query, that will bring one record with the sender 1, receiver 2 and then sender 2, receiver 1. I don't need these two record because this is a communication between same user 1 and user 2. I need one the latest one for the user specified with each of other users.

Thanks,

Comment: Wouldn't `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE (sender = 1 || receiver = 1) ORDER BY sendtime DESC LIMIT 3;` work?

Comment: No, that query will give the result with message between user 1 and 2 twice. I mean I need unique recent message between user.

Comment: I guess you could use `DISTINCT` then: `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM <table> WHERE (sender = 1 || receiver = 1) ORDER BY sendtime DESC LIMIT 3`

Comment: Be specific, what out put u want

Comment: I have shown in my question, the output that I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT data.* FROM 
(SELECT MAX(sendtime) AS sendtime 
         FROM data 
         WHERE 1 IN (sender,receiver)
         GROUP BY IF (1 = sender,receiver,sender)) AS latest
LEFT JOIN data ON latest.sendtime = data.sendtime AND 1 IN (data.sender, data.receiver)
GROUP BY IF (1 = data.sender,data.receiver,data.sender)
```

I recommend to use unique sequence id in your table to avoid external `GROUP BY`.
If you have incrementing unique `message_id` (i.e. bigger `message_id` corresponds to later `sendtime`), the query would be much simpler:

```
SELECT data.* FROM 
(SELECT MAX(message_id) AS message_id 
         FROM data 
         WHERE 1 IN (sender,receiver)
         GROUP BY IF (1 = sender,receiver,sender)) AS latest
LEFT JOIN data USING(message_id)
```

Comment: From this query as well, I get the record with user1 being a sender and receiver to user 2, so two records for user 1 while communicating with user 2. Can we have only one latest record from the communication with user 2, whether user1 being sender or receiver?

Comment: Oh, I didn't noticed the additional filter by user. I've edited answer.

Comment: Can we have only one latest record from the communication with user 2, whether user1 being sender or receiver?

Comment: This solution seem to be quite closer just had a few stuffs that does not work out. It does not show the records for communication between 1 and 4. The record appear with all null values. Any solutions?

Comment: For the moment, I thought I could not achieve that in single query!! But you really saved my day. Thanks, @vearutop. The solution was great!

Comment: Also, regarding your recommendation, If I have primary key in that table, would the group by condition in your query changes?

Answer (score 0):

Try making message as the primary key and put sender and receiver in 2 separate tables for the same message like this:

```
Table 1: {message, sender, sendtime}
Table 2: {message, receiver, sendtime}
```

Comment: If we make message the primary key, how can we maintain the same message between users. Wouldn't the primary key should be unique as well. But message cannot not be unique and we cannot add any other key combination to make it unique as well, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  Distinct (*)
FROM    tableName   m
WHERE   date =
    (
    SELECT  MAX (date)
    FROM    tableName

    )
```

Comment: It will pull only a record with the max value of date. And also, it does not fit to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To me it feels simpler to use an own ID based on the sender and receiver. No `JOIN` and just one `GROUP BY` needed:

```
SELECT sender, receiver, message, MAX(time)
FROM (
  SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN sender < receiver 
              THEN CONCAT(sender,'&', receiver)
              ELSE CONCAT(receiver,'&', sender) END AS fromto
  FROM data) AS a
GROUP BY fromto
```

Answer (score 0):

I take 30 mins to find the solution for this problem because I have thew  same problem
**just take it simple**

```
SELECT DISTINCT sent_by FROM messages WHERE sent_to = 1 UNION SELECT DISTINCT sent_to FROM messages WHERE sent_by = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work out

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE `sender`='$userNumber' OR `receiver`='$userNumber' ORDER BY `sendtime` DESC LIMIT 0,1";
```

Comment: This query also does not fit to my scenario