# MySQL group by and sort by each group record's last id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a messages table.

[image]

I want show people who send or recieve message with user named "Mean" and sort by **read=no** and **id (desc)**. So the correct sorting should be;

1167--Cevatkar--Mean-no- ..................

1168--Çetinceviz--Mean-yes- ..............

1164--Mean--Mervee-yes- ......................

My sql query is

```
SELECT * from messages
where to = 'Mean' or from = 'Mean' 
group by from,to
order by read='no',id DESC
limit 5
```

However, the query sorts the results incorrectly. When I echo the ids, I see that the query doesnt fetch the each group's (from or to = "Mean") last id. What is the correct way to do it ?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I understand your suggestion, however, that should not comes with a "-1" vote.

Comment: You're using grouping WITHOUT aggregate functions, leaving the DB free to pick what record will provide the value for each field in the group results. For mysql, that's usually the FIRST encountered value, but is not always guaranteed to be so. What you want cannot be done with a single query. you need one query to find the "max" of each group, then use those results to fetch the rest of the matching records.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure you really want to be using `GROUP BY` here. Nothing you said indicates you want an aggregate of anything.

Comment: This question shows no research effort. It's not clear nor (I suspect) particularly useful - but it's only my opinion.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29678702/query-for-the-latest-message-in-each-conversation-with-every-other-user) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095024/select-the-latest-message-between-the-communication-of-two-user-in-mysql) might point you in the right direction.